# Latest version of HTML2CANVAS does not work in Chrome, Firefox

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I have updated html2canvas from 0.4 to 1.0.0 and I used the function below to take a screenshot.

The function and html2canvas does not work and I got the error below.

How do I solve it?

> icefaces-compat.js.jsf?ln=ice.compat&v=3_3_0_130416:1 2ms html2canvas:
>   onrendered option is deprecated, html2canvas returns a Promise with
>   the canvas as the value

```
function screenshotChrome() {
    var target = $(document.body);
    html2canvas(target, {
        useCORS: true,
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            canvas.UniversalToBlob(function (blob) {
                    saveAs(blob, "aScreenshot.png");
                },
                "image/png", 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: As the warning suggests...`html2canvas()` now returns a promise. For example `html2canvas(...).then(canvas => ...)`

Comment: guessing people do not search error messages anymore https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/1610

Answer (score 7):

I'm not familiar with the library, but the error says that this version uses a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead of using the `onrendered` callback option. Therefore, it is (probably) used like:

```
html2canvas(target, {
  useCORS: true
})
  .then(function (canvas) {
    canvas.UniversalToBlob(function (blob) {
      saveAs(blob, "aScreenshot.png");
    }, "image/png", 1);
  })
  .catch(function (err) { console.log(err); });
```

Comment: I think your suggestion is a good solution, but I cannot load the picture for screenshot. Event {isTrusted: true, type: "error", target: img, currentTarget: null, eventPhase: 0, …}
bubbles
:
false
cancelBubble
:
false
cancelable
:
false
composed
:
false
currentTarget
:
null
defaultPrevented
:
false
eventPhase
:
0
isTrusted
:
true
path
:
(6) [img, form#mainForm.iceFrm, body#_t4, html, document, undefined]
returnValue
:
true
srcElement
:
img
target
:
img
timeStamp
:
52486.20000004303
type
:
"error"
__proto__
:
Event

Comment: @Yamur Unfortunately, I don't know much about the library. If you post the entire event (include the Event prototype at the end and expand the ellipses) in your question it might provide a little context and I'll try to help, but no guarentees.

Comment: the error through catch is Chrome error is: TypeError: canvas.UniversalToBlob is not a function

Comment: after I change to .toBlob start to work properly, but the problem is the picture quite not good.

Comment: What do you think the problem with CSS to not to show the proper design?

Comment: @Yamur: Again, I only came here to answer the question you asked. You have a follow-up question that is outside the scope of my knowledge and this question; feel free to open a new question on that. But I only was here to solve you with this specific problem, and (I believe) that problem was solved. Consider accepting this answer and asking a new question.